# Is the phrase "going on" grammatical?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

> 'She looked 16 going on 25'.

'Going on' means almost. The phrase 'going on' what does this mean grammatically?

Can somebody says that 'going' is the present participle of the verb 'be' and 'on' is a preposition?

If somebody says that 'going on' is an adverb, will he be wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of - https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/78016/meaning-of-8-going-on-48, although the top answer has not been accepted by the OP.

Comment: @Marios, welcome to ELL Stack Exchange!  Please read the [guide for new contributors.](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide-to-english-language-learners) Your question should have an appropriate title.  Thank you and keep contributing!

Comment: Agreed --- There is a good answer to this question:--  https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/78016/meaning-of-8-going-on-48#answer-78017